# Object of type 'System.Reflection.MdFieldInfo' cannot be converted to type 'MyEnum'

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, reflection

I am loading an assembly at runtime and trying to do a lot of operations at runtime which is going too far but anyways this is what I am trying to achieve:

I have a class called student in a foreign assembly which I am loading at runtime

```
public class Student
{
    public bool IsGood { get; set; }
    public StudentType St { get; set; }
    public University University { get; set; }
}
```

I can dynamically load the object from assembly by doing something like:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("//path");

Type type = assembly.GetType("TestFrameWork.Student");
var student = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Now, comes the turn to set the properties which are also with some  type dynamically loaded from the foreign assembly.

```
Type UniversityType = assembly.GetType("TestFrameWork.University");
type.GetProperty("University").SetValue(student, Activator.CreateInstance(UniversityType), null);
```

Nice part is that it works too!!

But

here is where problem starts. when i try to assign StudentType which is an enum from the same assembly it fails with error

> Object of type 'System.Reflection.MdFieldInfo' cannot be converted to
>
> type 'MyEnum'

This is how I am trying to set it:

```
type3 = assembly.GetType("TestFrameWork.StudentType");
type.GetProperty("St").SetValue(student, type3.GetField("Good"), null);
```

This code fails..

Comment: Your question is about `MdFieldInfo` & `MyEnum` but you never showed them in your code.

Comment: I am sorry for confusion its not MyEnum it's StudentType and MdFieldInfoe is something .Net is throwing error on. I have no idea where it came form. My best guess is that is it subtype of FieldInfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a `Field.GetValue` here

```
type.GetProperty("St").SetValue(student, type3.GetField("Good").GetValue(instance), null);
```

`Type.GetField` returns `FieldInfo` but what you actually need to pass as a parameter is enum value.

Note: I assume `Good` is a field on `type3` which is of type Enum `StudentType`

Comment: What do you mean by instance here?

Comment: Object instance of `type3` if it is a static field then `null` is enough

Comment: type3 refers to the enum and it is not static

Comment: Your assumtion here `Note: I assume Good is a field on type3 which is of type Enum StudentType` is absolutely correct. But enum is not static

Comment: `type.GetProperty("St").SetValue(student, type3.GetField("Good").GetValue(Activator.CreateInstance(type3), null);` worked!!

Comment: then you need to pass instance of type3 there, as like you pass `student` in `SetValue`